# How to Save the data in Array of object in MongoDb using Node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is My Model, I am trying to save the data in the Tools array of the Model.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var toolSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String},
    tools: [{
        jira: {
            url: {type: String},
            userName: {type: String},
            passWord: {type: String},
            status: {type: Boolean, default: false}
        },
        test1: {
            token: {type: String},
            uri: {type: String}
        },
        test2: {
            uri: {type: String}
        },
        test3: {
            uri: {type: String}
        }
    }]

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Tool', toolSchema);
```

Here is My code to save the Data

```
var Tools = require("../models/tool");
    exports.create = function (req, res) {
        var toolArr = req.body.tools;
        console.log(toolArr);
        var apps = new Tools();
        toolArr.forEach(function (item, index) {
            if (item.jira) {
                console.log(item.jira.userName);
                apps.tools.jira.userName = item.jira.userName;
                apps.save(function (err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log('Error in saving the Devops: ' + err);
                        throw err;
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log(result);
                        res.send(result);
                    }

                });
            }

        })
    };
```

I am not able to save the data in mongodb i am Getting Error, can any body help me on this.
i am sending the data using postman Like this.

```
tools[0][jira][userName]:Developer
```

Comment: You're doing a synchronous loop and using asynchronous methods inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

Error located ->`apps.tools.jira.userName = ...` according to your schema, `tools` is an array and doesn't have a `.jira`. You probably want to to do `apps.tools[index].jira.userName = ...`. Also I'd recommend not running an `apps.save()` inside your `.forEach()` since that'll make multiple writes to your db, but I don't know your exact use case.

Answer (score 0):

If the `req.body.tools` contains the array of objects like the schema format

```
var apps = new Tools();
apps.tools = req.body.tools;
 apps.save(function(err,result){
   if (err) {
      console.log('Error in saving the Devops: ' + err);
      throw err;
   } else {
        res.send(result);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Example of sending your data from postman

```
{
    "name":"abc",
     "tools":[
        {
            "jira":{
                "url":"www.abc.com",
                "userName":"abvc",
                "password":"123"
            },
            "test1":{
                "token":"your token",
                "uri":"www.anything.com"
            }
        }         
            ]
}
```

And then save your data by this code

```
var Tools = require("../models/tool");
var apps = new Tools();
var data=req.body /* assuming it as a post request and data is send in body */ 
apps(data).save(function(err,result){
if(err){
   throw err;
}else {
         res.send(result);
      }
});
```